# What if Xamarin Forms DependencyService has multiple implementation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my portable solution, i have a DependencyService Interface `IScanner`.

In my Android solution, i have 2 classes implementing this interface i.e.

```
public class Scanner1 : IScanner

public class Scanner2 : IScanner
```

So, now when i call `DependencyService.Get<IScanner>()` from portable, how do i add the logic to send one of the above implementations?

Answer (score 4):

DependencyService is a very limited service and designed for a specific purpose. You could create a facade class implementing the service and using one of the 2 implementations based on run-time logic (if that is your goal). Register the facade with DependencyService instead of the other two. Put the logic of which one to use inside the facade.

For more features I suggest you look into XLabs.Ioc abstraction layer and pick one of the many IOC providers from there. I am the author of it but even if you don't use the abstraction layer you will find crossplatform compatible DI containers from there that might suit your needs better.

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=xlabs.ioc

For more information I suggest taking a look at Matt's article on how it is used: http://www.codenutz.com/autofac-ninject-tinyioc-unity-with-xamarin-forms-labs-xlabs/

Quick sample using DependencyService and facade is below.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ScannerFacade))]
namespace DiSample.Droid
{
    public class ScannerFacade : IScanner
    {
        private readonly IScanner primaryScanner;
        private readonly IScanner secondaryScanner;

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor so <see cref="DependencyService"/> can resolve.
        /// </summary>
        public ScannerFacade() : this(new Scanner1(), new Scanner2())
        {
        }

        public ScannerFacade(IScanner primaryScanner, IScanner secondaryScanner)
        {
            this.primaryScanner = primaryScanner;
            this.secondaryScanner = secondaryScanner;
        }

        public bool IsAvailable
        {
            get { return this.primaryScanner.IsAvailable || this.secondaryScanner.IsAvailable; }
        }

        public Task DoSomething()
        {
            if (this.primaryScanner.IsAvailable) return this.primaryScanner.DoSomething();
            if (this.secondaryScanner.IsAvailable) return this.secondaryScanner.DoSomething();

            throw new System.InvalidOperationException("No scanners are available.");
        }
    }
}
```

IScanner interface I used for the example:

```
public interface IScanner
{
    bool IsAvailable { get; }
    Task DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SKall. 

The problem that i am facing is :
I have a DependencyService callled IBarcodeScanner.

In my android project, i have 2 types or barcode scanners implemention IBarcodeScanner.

At runtime, i want to check which is connected to the device and pass the appropriate implementation to the dependency service.

Comment: Then you want to implement a service facade and register that with the dependency service. Do not register the actual implementations but instead use them inside the facade.

Comment: Thank you SKall. I know i am asking too much. But, is it possible for you to provide a sample code of this approach?

Comment: I edited my answer above. Like said I don't recommend DependencyService for this kind of functionality as it quickly gets complicated and rather inflexible. Configuring a more complete DI container is a better solution in the long run.

Comment: Thanks a lot SKall :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the DependencyService to find your implementation, you need to add an assembly attribute to the assembly containing the type that registers it:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(Scanner1))]
```

This won't allow you to use run-time logic to decide which implementation to use, but it does allow you to specify it at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

By registering the class that you want, before calling the Get method.

```
DependencyService.Register<IScanner,Scanner1>();
```

Then this calls the GetSomething() method of Scanner1 class:-

```
var x = DependencyService.Get<IScanner>().GetSomething();
```